# How to resolve Magento product count errors?

Tags: e-commerce, magento-1.6, magento

I am working on a Magento website. I have been adding products for a while now. Now the website is about to go live in a few days just working on finishing touches.

There are several categories.. Suppose **Stools**. In the admin it shows it has 989 Products but in the Front End it shows it has 677 Products. The problem is coming up with many categories.

I thought there is some problem so I added another Category named :- **Ottawa Senators** under **Stools -> NHL Logo Stools**. I selected 15 products that has to be there. But in the front end it shows 7 Products only.

I have attached a screenshot which best describes the issue well.!

[screenshots](https://i.stack.imgur.com/98nVC.png)

Comment: In addition to Tim's comment, check that products have status 'enabled'

Comment: 1) "Can you please help me plz plz. " ... not very professional. 2) you didn't mention any action you tried before asking the question: reindex, check config section (display out of stock products), and so on... so you actually don't provide any relevant information and complain that is not working...

Answer (score 2):

Check (or better do batch update) that all of your products:

- are in stock (inventory tab)
- have positive qty (same tab)
- have correct website selected (websites tab)

PS: Senators are chokers.

Comment: Also, in the "General" tab, check that "Status" is active, "Visibility" is either "Catalog" or "Catalog, Search".

Answer (score 0):

Ofcourse the count is different because not everything in backend shows in the frontend

Examples :-

- Out of stock products ( if you configured to hide out of stock )
- Disabled products  Not Visible individually products Products which
- Product not assign to website
- Product not assign to some category so you can only see them with direct url
- You have to re-index catalog flat products and categories ( if you
  are using Flat Tables in configuration )

Answer (score 0):

You need to be concious about the cache management , Goto System > Cache management (Flush magento cache and Flush cache Storage).
Index Management should be ready to use.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I found the solution:
Take a backup of your database first and then run this query

```
DELETE FROM catalog_category_product where product_id NOT IN (SELECT entity_id FROM (catalog_product_entity))
```